# R: Apply conditionally over subsets with excluded values

Tags: r, subset, apply

Below is a data example that I have in `R`. Each observation in 'column A`has an assigned letter in`column B`, and an assigned value in`column C`. I want to add a`column D`that records a ratio  for each observation in`column A`. Below is an example calculation of the ratio for observation "1".

For each observation of "1", I want to count  **all** x's that appear in the table but are not assigned to "1". In this case, the count is 2 because there are two X's assigned to observation "3". In addition to the said condition, I want to count the X's--that are not assigned to observation "1"-- with a **value greater than 6** in `column C`. The count is 1 because one of the two X's assigned to "3" has a value greater than 6 in `column C`. Therefore, in `column D`, the ratio for each of the observation "1" is 1 over 2: 1/2.

And I want to do for the Y's in `column B` as well.

```
data_table
Column A   Column B  Column C
 1           X         7
 1           X         8
 1           X         3
 1           X         3
 2           Y         3
 2           Y         8
 3           X         5
 3           X         7
 4           Y         6
 4           Y         7
 4           Y         8
```

I would like the resulting table to look like this:

```
Column A  Column B  Column C Column D
 1           X         7      1/2     #There are two x's assigned to "3", and one of which has a value greater than 6 in column C.
 1           X         8      1/2
 1           X         3      1/2
 1           X         3      1/2
 2           Y         3      2/3
 2           Y         8      2/3
 3           X         5      2/4
 3           X         7      2/4
 4           Y         6      1/2
 4           Y         7      1/2
 4           Y         8      1/2
```

Here is the code that I have come up with so far, but for each observation in `column A`, I failed to generate `nrow` counts that skip over X's assigned to **that observation**.

```
    final_df %>% group_by(column_B) %>% 
    mutate(ratio = nrow(filter(final_df, column_C>6))/nrow(final_df))
```

Any suggestion on how I can modify this to exclude X's from a particular observation ( `column A`) in calculating the  proportion of X's with a value greater than 6 (in `column C`)

Thank you!

Comment: You ask for `number of x's that are not assigned to "1"`. In the 4 rows with Column_A == 1 that would be 0. That would make a poor choice as a denominator. I think you need to review the description of your problem. To my reading, it bears little connection to the desired result.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. I just edited the description. There are two x's assigned to "2", so two is the denominator. One of the assigned X has a value greater than 6 in column C, so the numerator is one.

Comment: I fail to see "two X's assigned to 2". I see two Y's in rows defined by "2".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something simple like this?

```
## Simulate some data
id1 <- rep(round(runif(250, 0,1)*100000000),each=4)
id2 <- rep(round(runif(50, 0,1)*100000000),each=4)
id2 <- rep(id2, each=5)
value <- rnorm(1000, mean=6, sd=2)
df <- data.frame(id1, id2, value)

## Calculate using a loop
output <- data.frame(id1, id2, prop=NA)
output <- output[!duplicated(output),]
for(i in 1:nrow(output)){
    gt6 <- sum(df$value[df$id2!=output$id2[i]]>6)
    tot <- sum(df$id2!=output$id2[i])
    output$prop[i] <- gt6/tot
}
```